# Cordova device ready doesn't work on xcode simulator but work on device

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios-simulator, device

don't know why but the device ready event doesn't work anymore on xcode simulator, but it's works on my iphone device.

Here my function:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {}
```

and the meta tag i have try but don't succeed:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap: ws: https://ssl.gstatic.com;img-src 'self' data: content:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: blob:;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

it works also with the phonegap application on device.

If anyone have an idea, if you need more explications tell me.

Excuse me for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i was using mac os X on vmware and it was very slow, i have try with an other pc more powerfull and it's work... Just good to know that simulator bug if it's too slow to load

Answer (score 0):

Have you try removing all of your meta to exclude any other reasons?
Your onDeviceReady don't seems to return anything. How do you know it does not fired?
Something like this could help tracking.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
console.log('deviceready fired');
}
```

Comment: yes sorry my function have a console.log('deviceready fired'); and it isn't fired, i have show only the structure... And yes i have try all the meta (one by one), and without meta, nothing works